# Jquery Trigger Method not working by Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to trigger an upload box (browse button) using jQuery.
The method I have tried now is:

```js
$('#testFile').trigger("click");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="testFile" />
```

IE works but Chrome does not.
Chrome version is 71. but version 81 is working.

Please help me.

Comment: There's nothing you can do about this not working in Chrome 71. However no one should be using that version

Comment: so here a little thing is not clear. when you want to perform this action? on window load?

Answer (score 0):

In the console of the developer tools is the following warning:

```
jquery.js:8510 File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation.
```

A solution could it be to handle the trigger through the click on a button like this example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#testButton').on('click', triggerFile);

  function triggerFile() {
    $('#testFile').trigger("click");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="testFile" />
<button type="button" id="testButton">Test</button>
```